# Scales Divs to content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a page that can run at full screen but as it scales down the divs drop and fit the content and allow scrolling. At fullscreen I'd like one big box with three little boxes on the bottom. The content in the big box changes dynamically so the div needs to be able to scale on a lower resolution device. Also, on a lower resolution device I would like the bottom three boxes to stack on top of one another and all be a fixed width to fit all of their contents. My main issue is text spilling out of the big box and being unreadable on smaller screens.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="widget1">
            <div class="widget_contents">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget2">
            <div class="widget_contents">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="widget3">
            <div class="widget_contents">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
html{height: 100%;}
body{height: 100%;}

.container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(150, 50, 50, 1);
}

.footer {
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.widget1 {
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    float: left;
}

.widget2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    float: left;
}

.widget3 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 1em;
    float: left;
}

.widget_contents {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(55, 150, 55, 1);
}
```

Here is a jdfiddles of my basic layout: http://jsfiddle.net/kzoqwz9n/

Thanks!

Comment: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For allow scrolling, you just need to apply 'overflow:auto;' to your block.

For stack bottom blocks you need to use media queries, something like :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .widget1,.widget2,.widget3 {
        padding-left: 1em;
        float:none;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

This exemple will stack your box when the screen is smaller than 600px.

UPDATE :

For the scrolling thing, we need to apply some changes :

```
.container {
    min-height: 80%;
    margin: 1em 1em 0 1em;
    background: rgba(150, 50, 50, 1);
}
```

We delete the style for .content and add 'padding-top: 1em;' to .footer

Exemple here : http://jsfiddle.net/kzoqwz9n/3/

It is what you want to do ? (try to add/remove content)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The media queries will definitely do the trick for the bottom blocks. I think I was a little unclear about the scrolling though. I meant for the div to expand and the whole page to scroll when the content would otherwise spill over.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to apply different rules depending on the viewport size and possibly device orientation and [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) for switching between row and column layout

> My main issue is text spilling out of the big box and being unreadable on smaller screens.

set the width to [`width: fit-content;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) (+ vendor prefixes) to allow the box itself instead of just the text content to spill out of the parent container